# $state.go in resolve not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I have these routes set up:

```
.state('createOrder', {
    url: '/customer-services/orders/create',
    templateUrl: 'tpl/customerServices/orders/save.html',
    controller: 'SaveOrderController',
    controllerAs: 'controller',
    resolve: {
        order: ['SaveOrderService', function (shared) {
            shared.order = { forDelivery: true };
        }]
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        pageTitle: 'Add order'
    }
}).state('createOrder.lines', {
    url: '/lines',
    views: {
        '@': {
            templateUrl: 'tpl/customerServices/orders/save/line.html',
            controller: 'SaveOrderLinesController',
            controllerAs: 'controller'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        validate: ['$state', 'SaveOrderService', function ($state, shared) {

            // If we don't have an account number
            if (!shared.order.accountNumber) {

                console.log('redirecting');

                // Redirect to the create order view
                $state.go('createOrder');
            }
        }]
    },
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        pageTitle: 'Add order : Lines'
    }
})
```

But the state does not change. I thought that there might be an error somewhere, so I subscribed the the state events like this:

```
// On state change
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
    var data = toState.data; // Get our state data
    var requireLogin = typeof data === 'undefined' ? false : data.requireLogin; // Check to see if we have any data and if so, check to see if we need login rights
    var user = service.get(); // Get our current user

    console.log(toState);

    $rootScope.currentUser = user; // Set our current user on the rootScope

    // If we require login rights and we are not authenticated
    if (requireLogin && !user.authenticated) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stop processing

        $state.transitionTo('login'); // And redirect to the login page
    }
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', function () {
    console.log('state not found');
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function () {
    console.log('state errored');
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    console.log('state changed');
});
```

and when I refresh my **lines** view, the console outputs this:

```
Object { url: "/lines", views: Object, resolve: Object, data: Object, name: "createOrder.lines" } app.js:42:9
redirecting app.js:2436:21
Object { url: "/customer-services", templateUrl: "tpl/customerServices/index.html", controller: "CustomerServicesController", controllerAs: "controller", data: Object, name: "customerServices" } app.js:42:9
state changed app.js:63:9
Object { order: Object, account: null, collectionPoint: null }
```

As you can see, the states think they have changed, but I still see the **createOrder.lines** view.
Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: did you include `validate` dependency of your `SaveOrderLinesController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out you don't need the promise. Just adding the timeout works. 
I found another post which suggests that the timeout is needed to avoid digest issues (which I am guessing is what is causing my states to not change).
Here is the final code:

```
validate: ['$state', '$timeout', 'SaveOrderService', function ($state, $timeout, shared) {

    // If we don't have an account number
    if (!shared.order.accountNumber) {

        // Timeout to avoid digest issues
        $timeout(function () {

            // Redirect to the create order view
            $state.go('createOrder');
        });
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to wrap the $state change in a function that will trigger a digest cycle whilst also rejecting the promise in the resolve method...

```
$timeout(function() { $state.go("createOrder") });
return $q.reject("Rejection message!");
```

Remember to inject $timeout and $q into your resolve function! =)

Should also add that rejecting the resolve will fire stateChangeError.

Comment: but there are no promises? or am I missing something?

Comment: in your original no there are no promises, but you can use them to signal to the router that the state change should not succeed. It'd be better handled in stateChangeStart but I can see you'd need to access the SaveOrderService in order to determine this.

Comment: what is the purpose of the timeout function?

Comment: the $timeout kicks off another digest - tells angular to update - it can be triggered immediately, hence no number passed in